# Android remote lock

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to create an android application to remotely lock another android phone. Note, the phone other phone to be locked will also have the said application installed on  it.

Comment: what do you mean by "lock"?

Comment: I mean not been able to be accessed or used anymore

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if your app is registered as a Device Admin. You can lock the screen, change the unlock password or do a factory reset. You can communicate with the Device Admin remotely if desired. Check the Device Admin docs on https://developer.android.com

Comment: Is it possible to make the application persistence even after factory reset

Comment: I don't think it is.